# Visual Studio creates empty directory structure inside project folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

So i have been messing around with the csproj XML file and i finally managed to make it work as i wanted 
using the bellow code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\src\**\*.cs">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The final effect is the auto-discovery of cs files in my source folder, meaning that i can create the sources externally and with a project reload (By unloading and reloading the project) it just creates a mirror of the filesystem as it is on my src folder!

Everything works fine, but there is only a minor side effect:
When i open the solution, Visual Studio creates an empty directory structure in the project folder (where the .csproj file is located) same as the one in my src folder. It contains no files, just the directory structure.

I tried building the project from the command line using msbuild and everything works fine, and no directory structure is generated, so i suppose that it is some kind of side effect from the Visual Studio side.

Any help is appreciated :)